# Order items from phpmyadmin in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, content-management-system, phpmyadmin

I am trying to do a simple CMS in PHP. In Slider management, I want to change order of photos which were added.

```
<a href="slideup.php?order=<?php echo $result['order']; ?>&id=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" title="Up"><img src="../images/up.png" alt="Up" /></a>
<a href="slidedown.php?order=<?php echo $result['order']; ?>&id=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" title="Down"><img src="../images/down.png" alt="Down" /></a>
```

It is sending related php pages, current order and id of slide.

**slideup.php**

```
<?php

    include('includes/functions.php');

    $order=$_REQUEST['order'];
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];

    goUp($order, $id);

?>
```

**slidedown.php**

```
<?php

    include('includes/functions.php');

    $order=$_REQUEST['order'];
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];

    goDown($order, $id);

?>
```

**functions.php**

```
function goUp($order, $id)
    {
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();
        if(!$order == 1)
        {
            $neworder = $order - 1;
            mysql_query("UPDATE `slider` SET `order`='$order' WHERE `order`='$neworder'") or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query("UPDATE `slider` SET `order`='$neworder' WHERE `id`='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
        }       

        header('Location: ../admin/slider.php');
    }

function goDown($order, $id)
    {
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();

        $totalslide = 0;
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) as count FROM `slider`") or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $totalslide = $result['count'];

        if(!$order == $totalslide)
        {
            $neworder = $order + 1;
            mysql_query("UPDATE `slider` SET `order`='$order' WHERE `order`='$neworder'") or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query("UPDATE `slider` SET `order`='$neworder' WHERE `id`='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
        }       

        header('Location: ../admin/slider.php');
    }
```

When i clicked icons, code was working without any problem. But as a result, nothing happens. Is there a problem about my code or a logical mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: OT: your current code is vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

After your mysql_query() put this because I believe you have a mysql error:

```
echo mysql_error();
```

Let us know what it says.  When you write a query, you should only be surrounding the value with single quotes if the field is a varchar, date, etc. but not for numbers and such.  I'm guessing your ID is a number, and it seems your ORDER is a number too, so in your update you should have something like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `slider` SET `order`=$neworder WHERE `id`=$id") or die(mysql_error());
```

That should at least get you started, although you may have logic issues because I don't really understand why you're updating every row in the slider table changing the old order to the new order regardless of ID.

Comment: `echo mysql_error();` gives me nothing. Single quotes changed nothing, because you do it. It won't give you an error. I'm updating slider table because I'm keeping my slide information there. Also while I'm displaying, getting data from database. Is it a bad approach for these situationss?